# How to render Three.js scene inside a column?

Tags: html, three.js, multiple-columns, responsive

I have succesfully created a ThreeJS scene. Now I want to show the scene only in one column and let the other one free for information.

I have tried using "document.getElementById( 'canvas' )" but it only allows me to resize the scene with a static size. I want it to render in the first column, no matter the column size. Even the controls of the scene are showing in the top of the page, and they should be in the top of the scene.

Could you help me?
This is the code so far.

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/107/three.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

<!-- FIRST COLUMN -->
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div id="canvas">
        Text
     </div>
    </div>

  <!-- SECOND COLUMN -->

    <div class="col-sm-7">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script>

  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight , 1, 2000 );

  var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 1 );
  scene.add( axesHelper );


  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  camera.position.z = 10;

  var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );


    renderer.render( scene, camera );
  };



  animate();




</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a working example using codepen.io or jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a THREE.WebGlRenderer with a specific canvas. See the canvas parameter in the constructor for [WebGLRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer)

First, add a canvas into your html

```
<!-- FIRST COLUMN -->
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <canvas id="canvas">
</div>
```

Then, tell your canvas to use the whole column

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

Then, create the renderer using your canvas.

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, canvas.width/canvas.height , 1, 2000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas:canvas
});
```